# How to show the tooltip on top of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

```
<html>
   <span ng-if="item.description!=''&&item.description!=null"><img tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip-html-unsafe="{{item.description}}" class="tooltip-icon malign" src="app/img/permission.png"/></span>
   <span ng-if="item.description==''||item.description==null"><img tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip-html-unsafe="No description available" class="tooltip-icon malign" src="app/img/permission.png"/></span>
</html>
```

I was facing issues which the edit and delete Tool tip is not fully displaying in the front screen.It is breaking behind the background screen.

Then i added the

```
position:fixed;
```

so after that the Tool tip was displaying correctly.

Comment: Question is not much clear. Be clear with your question.

Comment: The tooltip is not not displaying properly  the bottom of the tool tip is not showing while i click any button

Comment: What are you using for tool-tip is it is a bootstrap thing or else some other plugin..? you should mention it.

Comment: Please provide the relevant script and css in use

Comment: i'm not able to provide my scripts here. i'm using JS and css and angular js.the code which i have given here is ANgular js

Comment: _I have a div tag as follows:_....where? i didn't find any.

Comment: sry thats not right..see that html tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a very basic tooltip, you may just try

```
<img title="This is my tooltip"
```